# Approximate disk space consumption of rows on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, space, disk

I'd like to understand, what causes the size of a SQL Server 12 database. The mdf has 21.5 GB. Using the "Disk Usage by Top Tables" report in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see that 15.4 GB are used by the "Data" of one table. This table has 1,691 rows of 4 columns (int, varchar(512), varchar(512), image). I assume the image column is responsible for most of the consumption. But

```
Select (sum(datalength(<col1>)) + ... )/1024.0/1024.0 as MB From <Table>
```

only gives 328.9 MB.

What might be the reason behind this huge discrepancy?

Additional information: 
For some rows the image column is updated regularly.

This is a screenshot of the report:
[image]
If we can trust it, indices or unused space should not be the cause.

Comment: Interesting.  `datalength()` is not reliable for estimating the size of the table, but it shouldn't be off by a factor of 50.

Comment: Might want to pose this over at dba.stackexchange.com too.  Maybe a logging issue?

Comment: Is it possible that the current status is the result of several operations that left a lot of unused space inside the data pages. I had something similar recently when I applied the sparse option. To reclaim the space, you should use "ALTER DATABASE {database name} REBUILD"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a lot of indexes per table, these will all add up. Maybe your auto-grow settings are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was a long running transaction on another unrelated database (!) on the same SQL Server instance. The read committed snapshot isolation level filled the version store. Disconnecting the other application reduced the memory usage to a sensible amount.